# Extension doesn't work properly in collection view cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I am using this extension to center the text vertically inside my text view.

```
extension UITextView {

    func centerVertically() {
        let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
        let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
        contentOffset.y = -positiveTopOffset
    }
}
```

But for some reason it does not effect the textview when view loads. But when i scroll collection view cells 3 times, it works properly. I am calling the extension in this line. `cell.textView.centerVertically()`
 Any ideas?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let randomJoke = Int(arc4random()) % jokes.count
        cell.textView.text = jokes[randomJoke]
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 736 {
            cell.stackViewTop.constant = 40
            cell.stackViewBottom.constant = 100
        }
        cell.textView.centerVertically()
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `textAlignment` property on `UITextView` to `.center`?

Comment: Isn't it to center the text horizontally? What i am doing here is to center it vertically. Lets say i have a textview for 5 lines of text. But when i have 2 lines of text i want to center it vertically in textview

Comment: Good catch, I misread the issue.